# WebGL Framebuffer is Blank

Tags: javascript, webgl, typescript

I've created a framebuffer in WebGL using the code:

```
this.buffer = ctx.createFramebuffer();
ctx.bindFramebuffer(ctx.FRAMEBUFFER, this.buffer);

this.depthTexture = this.createTexture(ctx, ctx.DEPTH_COMPONENT, 
    ctx.DEPTH_COMPONENT, ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT);       
ctx.framebufferTexture2D(ctx.FRAMEBUFFER, ctx.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, 
    ctx.TEXTURE_2D, this.depthTexture, 0);


this.colourTexture = this.createTexture(ctx, ctx.RGBA, ctx.RGBA, ctx.FLOAT);        
ctx.framebufferTexture2D(ctx.FRAMEBUFFER, ctx.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
    ctx.TEXTURE_2D, this.colourTexture, 0);
```

draw to it using

```
this.ctx.useProgram(this.forwardShader.program);
this.ctx.bindFramebuffer(this.ctx.FRAMEBUFFER, this.framebuffer.buffer);
this.ctx.viewport(0, 0, this.framebuffer.size, this.framebuffer.size);
this.ctx.clear(this.ctx.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.ctx.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

mat4.identity(this.viewMatrix);
mat4.identity(this.modelMatrix);

this.camera.transform(this.viewMatrix);

mat4.translate(this.modelMatrix, this.modelMatrix, [0, 0, -2]);

this.mStack.pushMatrix(this.modelMatrix);

mat4.translate(this.modelMatrix, this.modelMatrix, [0, -1, 0]);
mat4.rotateX(this.modelMatrix, this.modelMatrix, -Math.PI / 2.0);

this.setShaderUniforms();
this.plane.draw(this.forwardShader);

this.mStack.popMatrix(this.modelMatrix);

this.setShaderUniforms();
this.cube.draw(this.forwardShader);

this.ctx.bindFramebuffer(this.ctx.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
```

and then render the result using

```
this.ctx.useProgram(this.renderTextureShader.program);
this.ctx.viewport(0, 0, this.viewportWidth, this.viewportHeight);    
this.ctx.clear(this.ctx.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.ctx.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

this.renderTexture.draw(this.framebuffer.colourTexture, this.renderTextureShader);
```

which works perfectly, however when I change it to render the depth texture I get a white screen. I've checked that the relevant extensions are enabled and stored them in an array (apparently if they get gc'ed it can cause bugs. Any feedback on what im doing wrong would be great

Full code can be found on my [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/timmutton/webgl-typescript)

Comment: Depth linearizing could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44357374/3012928

Answer (score 2):

It may be a problem with the range of your depth data, try:

`this.depthTexture = this.createTexture(ctx, ctx.DEPTH_COMPONENT, ctx.DEPTH_COMPONENT, ctx.FLOAT);`

Comment: Doing so causes the error "INVALID_OPERATION: texImage2D: invalid type for DEPTH_COMPONENT format". I suspect that whilst the extensions for depth textures & floating point textures are enabled, the two cant be combined as of yet